# I'd know my life before I had even lived it

Tags: tenses, sentence, ambiguity

> Girl: "I've made my decision, Father".
>
> Her Father: "You've ruined so many prospects, Lucy".
>
> Girl: "Hmm.Nothing but boys, following in their father's footsteps. **I'd
>   know my life before I had even lived it**".

Is this sentence (*I'd know my life before I had even lived it*) past or imaginary present? If it is past then why aren't we saying "I **knew** my life before I had even lived it"? What does "would" mean here?

Here is a link http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=savannah

It's from a movie 'Savannah'

Comment: Can I get an elaborate answer because I still can't know for sure whether it is present or past hypothetical

Comment: @snailboat Okay, I added more context and made it clear who is saying what here which is not clear from the script on the website

Comment: I have answered below, it is present conditional similar to "If I had got that promotion I wanted [in the past] I would be [present] the boss by now" - "If I had accepted one of those prospects [in the past] I would know [present] how the rest of my life would be mapped out"

Answer (score 2):

This is a conditional tense. I am not a grammar expert but I have seen this particular example called "present unreal conditional". However to understand why you have to realise that the condition is implied and is not actually present in the text:

"[If I had married one of them] I'd know my life before I had even lived it"

Comment: More pedantically, conditional _mood_, present tense.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound correct to me. First, grammatically the tenses should be changed to

> I'd **have known** my life before I had even lived it.

Then, the meaning, as I *imagine* it (I didn't find the line in the whole script), would be better conveyed by:

> I **was to know how** my life **unfolded** before I had even lived it.

If this is indeed what is meant then it depicts a past situation that never was, so it is a hypothetical past. It can be followed by:

> How did they even expect this from me?